# How to filter relations in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Let these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Word(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
```

And this view:

```
def main_page(request):
    words = Word.objects.all()
    return render(request, "main_page.html", {'words': words})
```

How can I filter words by categories passing a category as argument in a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the reverse relation:

```
{{ category.word_set.all }}
```